# `cd` up the canonical path

Tags: shell, symlink, cd-command

Consider:

```
$ pwd
/home/user
$ ls -l
total 3604
lrwxrwxrwx 1 user user  19 Nov 27 12:11 pages -> /var/www/pages/

$ cd pages
$ pwd
/home/user/pages
$ readlink -f .
/var/www/pages

$ cd ..
$ readlink -f .
/home/user
$
```

When I'm in `/var/www/pages` I would like to go up to `/var/www` however running `cd ..` brings me to `/home/user`. Obviously this is due to having gotten to `/var/www/pages` via a symlink. **How can I `cd` up one directory when I'm in a symlink?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`cd -P ..`
You should read more preciscly manual ;-)

Comment: Thanks! Actually, I tried to read the fine manual however `No manual entry for cd`, and `info cd` gives irrelevant information. This is on two Ubuntu systems.

Comment: cd is a build in shell command so so man is not exciting, but `man cd` give good result in google ;)

Comment: @dotancohen `cp --help` generally gives short info compared to the main page (or in this case, all the info since it doesn't have a man page)

Comment: @dotancohen Because `cd` is built in to the shell, you can find the documentation for it inside the shell manual (`man bash`).  Scroll down to the "SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS" section.  Also a general search for `cd` in that man page is illuminating; it will teach you about `$OLDPWD`, `$CDPATH`, and some other fun stuff.

Comment: `alias back=cd "$OLDPWD"`

Comment: @Rob No need for an alias, `cd -` takes you back to `$OLDPWD` already.

Comment: @dg99 thank you for that I didn't know this one.
`cd -` mean going to `$OLDPWD` and according to documentation: `- is equivalent to $OLDPWD` which also mean  `$OLDPWD The previous working directory as set by the cd command.` so none of what your saying is a solution

Comment: Even `cd --help` doesn't mention what `-P` does, though I will admit that I didn't try that before posting! In any case, `man bash` does have some terrific info and I should review it. Thank you all!

Comment: @Lekensteyn Yeah, but I can remember to type `back` if I want to go back a directory, and don't do it often enough to remember `cd -`